# cant list directories using ftputil

Tags: python, python-3.x

So,

I'm trying to list the content of the current directory on the ftp server and then list the directory after the file upload, but it's not working like i expected:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import ftplib
import ftputil


class OpenFTPSession(ftplib.FTP):

    def __init__(self, address, user, password, port):
        """
        port variable must be passed as int to avoid:
        File "C:\Python33\lib\ftplib.py", line 144, in connect
            if port > 0:
        TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int()
        """
        ftplib.FTP.__init__(self)
        self.connect(address, int(port))
        self.login(user, password)


class FileTransferUtils(object):

    def __init__(self, address, user, password, remote_path, port):
        self.host = address.split(':')[0]
        self.start = ftputil.FTPHost(self.host, user, password, remote_path, port=port, session_factory=OpenFTPSession)
        self.start.chdir(remote_path)

    def upload(self, filename):
        try:
            self.start.upload(filename, filename)
            self.start.listdir('/healthy_food/bacon_recipes')

            return True
        except Exception:
            raise


ftp_connect = resource_utilities.FileTransferUtils(
    self.address, self.user, self.password, self.remote_path, self.ftp_port
)

for package in glob.glob("*.zip"):
    #print("   Package: {}".format(package))
    #os.chmod(package, 0o666)
    # Upload package
    ftp_connect.upload(package)
```

Error Message:

```
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\ftputil\stat.py", line 499, in _real_listdir
    format(path))
ftputil.error.PermanentError: 550 /healthy_food/bacon_recipes: no such directory or wrong directory parser used
Debugging info: ftputil 3.0, Python 3.3.4 (win32)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just looking at the error (`Upload failed`) seems to imply that "can't list directories" is a bit misleading and that the main issue is `/healthy_food/bacon_recipes: no such directory or wrong directory parser used`. Check the directory exists maybe?

Comment: @JonClements The directory exists :) I'm running this as a test on my local ftp server

Comment: And does that directory exist relative to the root of the FTP login?

Comment: @JonClements Well, yes, i did some tests last night and i'm able to upload files to the directory, but cant get list working, I think i'll be able to solve this soon , just let me get my morning coffee

Comment: probably a good idea to [edit] your error message to be one relevant to the issue with listing the directory then if uploading is now working :)